Solving an exotic trigonometric function or a sextic
I'm an aerospace engineering student and I've been doing some analytical work on an interdisciplinary problem involving orbital mechanics and electromagnetism. In the final part of my work, I ended up with those four equations below
$$ e \cos\left(f - \omega \right) - 4 \cos\left(2 f + \omega \right) - 5 e \cos\left(3 f + \omega\right) =0;$$
$$ e \sin\left(f - \omega \right) + 2 e\cos\left( f+\omega \right) - 4 \sin\left(2 f + \omega \right) - 5 e \sin\left(3 f + \omega\right) =0;$$
$$-e \cos \omega + \cos\left(f + \omega \right) + 2 e \cos\left(2 f + \omega \right)=0;$$
$$-e \sin \omega  + \sin\left(f + \omega \right) + 2 e \sin\left(2 f + \omega \right)=0,$$
wher $e$ is the orbital eccentricity and $\omega$ is the argument of the periapsis. $e$ is always smaller than $1$ for my application, a Keplerian elliptical orbit. $\omega$ can have any value within the domain $[0,2\,\pi]$.
The first two equations are the roots of the electric current when the satellite does not have rotation. The last two equations are the roots of the electric current for the satellite when it has a rotation equal to the orbital period i.e. the satellite always keeps pointing toward Earth's center along the orbital path. I'm using Wolfram Mathematica, and for the first two equations, the software gave me that the roots for the first and second equations can be given by the roots of the following polynomials:
$$1 - e^2 + \cos 2 \omega + 
 e^2 \cos 2 \omega + \left(12 e + 4 e \cos 2 \omega\right) x + \left(-8 + 
    27 e^2 + 5 e^2 \cos 2 \omega\right) x^2 + \left(-50 e - 
    2 e \cos 2 \omega\right) x^3 + \left(8 - 75 e^2 - 
    5 e^2 \cos2 \omega \right)x^4 + 40 e x^5 + 50 e^2 x^6=0,$$
$$1 - 4 e^2 - \cos 2 \omega - 4 e^2 \cos 2 \omega + 
 16 e x + (-8 + 40 e^2 + 8 e^2 \cos 2 \omega) x^2 + (-54 e - 
    2 e \cos 2 \omega) x^3 + (8 - 85 e^2 - 
    5 e^2 \cos2 \omega) x^4 + 40 e x^5 + 50 e^2 x^6=0.$$
Unfortunately, it just gave me those polynomials solutions for the non-rotating satellite.
I'd like to know if have any method to solve the four first trigonometric equations, or at least the 2 polynomials that apply for the non-rotating satellite only. I've been able to find some specific solutions for arbitrary $e$ with $\omega=0$ and for arbitrary $e$ with $\omega=\pi/2$, which is just a mirrored version of the first solution I mentioned, i.e. arbitrary $e$ with $\omega=0$.
If anyone knows a method for solving those equations, I would be eternally grateful, even if it depends on some non-elementary functions like the Gamma function or the Zeta function. I dedicated so hard to this work and I'd like to have 100% analytical solutions, even though my engineers and colleagues won't use them because it is probably much simpler to find those roots with numerical methods like Newton's, that's how I'm verifying the validity of the already found solutions.
I appreciate your time to read this. Thanks for your support in advance!

If you label the four equations with $(1)$ to $(4)$, then $(3) + i(4)$, where $i$ is the imaginary unit, turns into $\exp(i\omega)(-e + x + 2ex^2) = 0$, where $x = \exp(if) = \cos f + i\sin f$. This means $x$ is the solution to a quadratic involving $e$, giving $x$ two possible solutions in terms of $e$. Since $x = \exp(if)$ has complex modulus $1$, this will greatly restrict the possible values of $e$ as well. From this, it should be possible to extract a limited possible set of pairs of values of $e$ and $f$, which I would then insert into $(1)$ and $(2)$, and see what you get.

Is it $e\lt 1$ or $|e|\lt1$ (can be $e=-5?$, What  $f$ is, please?

@Piquito, $f$ is the angle of the orbit, also called the true anomaly, it is the angle that gives us the information where the satellite is.
No, the eccentricity is always positive, $e=0$ is a circular orbit, $0<e<1$ is an eliptic orbit, $e=1$ is a parabolic orbit, $e>1$ is a hyperbolic orbit.

@TheoBendit, I'm sorry for taking so long to give you feedback, this algebraic manipulation does solve both equations. However, I can't use it to predict other solutions, like compare with the ones I already have, and does not match with numerical solutions I found with Newton's method.
However, it is a solution hahaha that's already great, Thanks!

I don’t know if this helps, but you can solve for $f$ equations (3) and (4) independently of the first two equations:
You have $$2e\cos(2f+\omega)=e\cos \omega-\cos(f+\omega)$$ and
$$2e\sin(2f+\omega)=e\sin\omega-\sin(f+\omega)$$
Squaring and adding these gives:
$$4e^2=e^2+1-2[e\cos\omega\cos(f+\omega)+e\sin\omega\sin(f+\omega)]$$
$$\implies 3e^2=1-2e\cos f$$

Using $(3)$, we have
$$\cos (2 \omega )=$$ $$\frac{50 e^2 x^6+\left(8-75 e^2\right) x^4+\left(27 e^2-8\right)
   x^2-e^2+40 e x^5-50 e x^3+12 e x+1 } { 5 e^2 x^4-5 e^2 x^2-e^2+2 e x^3-4 e x-1}$$
Using $(4)$, we have
$$\cos (2 \omega )=$$ $$\frac{50 e^2 x^6+40 e x^5+\left(8-85 e^2\right) x^4-54 e x^3+\left(40 e^2-8\right) x^2+16 e x-4
   e^2+1 } {5 e^2 x^4+2 e x^3-8 e^2 x^2+4 e^2+1}$$
Equating, and hoping that the denominator will not make any problem, we have
$$0=\left(e^2 x^2-2 e x-2 e^2-1\right)\times $$
$$ \left(50 e^2 x^6+40 e x^5+8\left(1-10 e^2\right) x^4-52 e x^3+\left(33e^2-8\right) x^2+14 e x+\left(1-2e^2\right)\right)$$
The first factor has solutions
$$x_\pm=\frac{1\pm \sqrt{2(e^2+1)}}{e}$$
The problem is not only to solve for $x$ but also to keep the solution(s) which give an acceptable result for $\cos (2 \omega )$.
Now, my questions are :
 `do you want the largest root for $x$ ?`

 `what is the range of $e$ ?`

 `what is the range of $x$ ?` 

Knowing the answers, I think that a few things could be done.
Edit
Beside the solutions of the quadratic, playing with a few values of $e$, what I noticed is that
$$x_*=\frac{45 e^2+56 e+15}{2 \left(23 e^2+29 e+8\right)}$$ approximates the largest solution of the sextic.
Update
Let $F(x,e)$ be the sextic equation. Drawing the level curve  $F(x,e)=0$ for $0\leq e\leq 1$, there are four continuous, increasing and not interescting lines which seem to be
$$ +0.92 < x_1 < +0.96\qquad\qquad +0.38 < x_2 < +0.65$$
$$ -0.40 < x_3 < +0.07\qquad\qquad -0.93 < x_4 < -0.52$$
The first one is the one I almost identified.
The contour plot did not allow me to see the other but they exist. Computing the roots with a $\Delta e=0.01$ revealed that there are also two other real roots in some regions.
Some estimates
A better approximation of the largest root is
$$x_*^{(1)}=\frac{1767 e^4+4336 e^3+3827 e^2+1442 e+200}{1813 e^4+4486e^3+4005 e^2+1532 e+216}$$  varies from $\frac{25}{27}$ (which is $0.926$) to $\frac{2893}{3013}$  (which is $0.960$). Since  $\forall e$, $F(x_*^{(1)},e) >0$ and  $F''(x_*^{(1)},e) >0$, by Darboux theorem, Newton method will converge without any overshoot during iterations. All of that means that $x_*$ is an underestimate of the solution.
For the next root
$$x_*^{(2)}=\frac{19839 e^4+28208 e^3+56432 e^2+20608 e+3584}{44618 e^4+34672e^3+80928 e^2+40448 e+9216}$$ varies from $\frac{7}{18}$ (which is $0.389$) to $\frac{128671}{209882}$  (which is $0.613$). The situation is not as good as for $x_*^{(1)}$ with respect to  Darboux theorem.

@EricD'Antona. What is thé answer ?

Answering your questions:
do you want the largest root for $x$ ?
No, I want all values of x which are solutions to the fourth equation
what is the range of $e$? 
The range of $e$ is $0\leq e<1$, $e$ is not a complex number, just real, strictly positive.
what is the range of $x$? 
I want to solve the first 4 equations, the polynomial equations are results Mathematica gives me when I use the Solve[] function on the first 2 trigonometric equations, respectively. It states that the solutions for the trigonometric equations are $\pm arcos$[roots of the polynomial 1 or 2]

I answered in the previous comments, about what I want with those equations, the range of $e$, and the range of $x$

There is one point I do not understand : in comments, you said that you use Newton method. Fine but this means that you have estimates. Would you clarify ? Thanks & cheers

Yes, I do have numerical solutions for the first 4 equations, since the solution of the polynomial becomes irrelevant if I use numerical methods to find the roots. I'd like an analytical solution to the problem. The sextic equation is just a result Mathematica shows me when I ask it to solve the first two trigonometric equations in the form:
$\pm$ArcCos[Root[... polynomial here...]]
I made a few numerical solutions for the polynomials, just to verify if the arccosine of its roots are solutions for the first equation, the same for the second polynomial, and the second equation.

I decided to ask here (stack exchange) because since I got those results, I've been reading on the internet how to solve general cases of the sextic equations, but I could only find papers on solutions for specific cases when certain conditions apply to the sextic. I'm aware that Abel-Rufini's theorem states that no solution on radicals can be found for a quintic or higher polynomials. A few days ago I read that Kampé de Fériet functions can solve general sextic, but could not find anything about applying this function to solve a sextic equation

But you're right about your analysis of the location of the roots!  At least for the applications I made, for $0<e<0.1$ the roots are really within those intervals you mentioned.
